# An "extra" solution to an initial value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I came up with this example when I was teaching:
consider the IVP
$$
y'(x) = xy-x-5y+5, y(0)=1.
$$

The standard approach is to separate variables: $y'(x) = (x-5)(y-1)$, which allows me to integrate $\int \frac{dy}{(y-1)} = \int (x-5) dx$, at this point I have $y-1 = e^C e^{x^2/2-5x}$ for some constant $C$, so to satisfies the initial value, I need $0=e^C$, clearly no such $C$ exists.

But if I "forces" $e^C=0$ by assuming that $C=-\infty$, then I have the solution $y(x) \equiv 1$, which solves the IVP perfectly.

I was confused that such a "wrong method" could give me the correct answer, can someone shed light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine the integrating constant to be $\tilde{C} \equiv e^C$, rewrite the solution as

$$ y = 1+\tilde{C} e^{x^2/2-5x}, $$

and simply set $\tilde{C} = 0$ to satisfy the initial condition. This is actually how most textbooks represent the solution to differential equations, I believe with the purpose of avoiding such problems.

Comment: I guess the question is more of a "justification" of taking $\tilde{C}=0$. i know the justification is simply that "it solves the IVP", perhaps I should just take it as it is...